# Sort XML elements in a file

Tags: c#, xml, format

I need to program a tool to sort XML Elements inside of a file, but I just cant do it.
The elements should be in a ascending order of the "Request ID".

This is my XML example.

```
 Appl: SendMessageToPT: XMLString=
<CardServiceRequest
   RequestType = ´CardFinancialAdvice´ ApplicationSender = ´50´ WorkstationID = ´SM-104131´ RequestID = ´3583>
</CardServiceRequest>

Appl: ReceiveMessageFromPT: XMLString=
<CardServiceResponse 
  RequestType=´CardFinancialAdvice´ ApplicationSender=´50´ WorkstationID=´SM-104131´ RequestID=´3508´ OverallResult=´Success´>
</CardServiceResponse>
```

So I should get my "SendMessageToPT" after I get the "ReceiveMessageFromPT".

**How can I do this in with C#?**

Comment: The code you show is neither code to sort XML, nor is it XML (because of the two lines that look like `Appl: SendMessageToPT: XMLString=`).  Can you show us your XML and the code you are using to try to sort it?

Comment: Yeah I know this is my problem. 
Thats my XML, I know its not in a correct form but thats the "XML" I get to work with...
I dont have any code to sort it, because I dont get it.

Comment: But I could remove these lines that aren't XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by op
[XML traversing using XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378810/xml-traversing-using-xmldocument)
You can use the [XmlDocument](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZ0-KXoePeAhWKqZAKHVZyCl0QFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.xml.xmldocument&usg=AOvVaw2HhPp6GY1cMXFT-1v0kVeO) class to traverse the nodes using XPath and then use your preferred algorithm to get the highest one.

Once again, copying the code from op and adapting it to your code it'd result in

I also strongly suggest you take a look at the System.Xml namespace.